# Yield a modified token in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a syntax like the following

```
Identifier
    : [a-zA-Z0-9_.]+
    | '`' Identifier '`'
    ;
```

When I matched an identifier, e.g `someone`, I'd like to strip the backtick and yield a different token, aka `someone`

Of course, I could walk through the final token array, but is it possible to do it during token parsing?

Comment: Do you mean that everything between backticks generates a token `SOMEONE` or that `'fred'` (between backticks) has to generate a token `FRED`, i.e. each backticked string produces a different token ?

Comment: @BernardK eaxcelty, is that possible?

Comment: Maybe with `setType`, but then you have hundreds of different tokens, how are you going to define the parser rules ?

Comment: You can override the emit function in the lexer to change the token text, or add an action to the rule, and strip the quotes there. If you use java call `setText`.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski can you provide a complete example? I do use java here

Comment: @daisy I don't use java so I won't go into a full example, but basically what I mean is: `IDENTIFIER: ... { setText(unquote(getText())); };` - you need to write the `unquote` method.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand, given the input (file `t.text`) :

```
one `someone`
two `fred`
tree `henry`
```

you would like that tokens are automatically produced as if the grammar had the lexer rules :

```
SOMEONE : 'someone' ;
FRED    : 'fred' ;
HENRY   : 'henry' ;
ID  : [a-zA-Z0-9_.]+ ;
```

But tokens are identified by a `type`, i.e. an integer, not by the name of the lexer rule. You can change this `type` with setType() :

```
grammar Question;

/* Change `someone` to SOMEONE, `fred` to FRED, etc. */

@lexer::members { int next_number = 1001; }

question
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 1117");}
    :   expr+ EOF
    ;

expr
    :   ID BACKTICK_ID
    ;

ID  : [a-zA-Z0-9_.]+ ;

BACKTICK_ID : '`' ID '`' { setType(next_number); next_number+=1; } ;

WS : [ \r\n\t] -> skip ;
```

Execution :

```
$ grun Question question -tokens -diagnostics t.text 
[@0,0:2='one',<ID>,1:0]
[@1,4:12='`someone`',<1001>,1:4]
[@2,14:16='two',<ID>,2:0]
[@3,18:23='`fred`',<1002>,2:4]
[@4,25:28='tree',<ID>,3:0]
[@5,30:36='`henry`',<1003>,3:5]
[@6,38:37='<EOF>',<EOF>,4:0]
Question last update 1117
line 1:4 mismatched input '`someone`' expecting BACKTICK_ID
line 2:4 mismatched input '`fred`' expecting BACKTICK_ID
line 3:5 mismatched input '`henry`' expecting BACKTICK_ID
```

The basic types come from the lexer rules :

```
$ cat Question.tokens 
ID=1
BACKTICK_ID=2
WS=3
```

the other from `setType`. Instead of incrementing a number for each token, you could write the tokens found in a table, and before creating a new one, access the table to check if it already exists and avoid duplicate tokens receive a different number.

Anyway you can do nothing useful in the parser because parser rules need to know the `type` number.

If you have a set of names known in advance, you can list them in a `tokens` statement :

```
grammar Question;

/* Change `someone` to SOMEONE, `fred` to FRED, etc. */

@lexer::header {
    import java.util.*;
}

tokens { SOMEONE, FRED, HENRY }

@lexer::members {
    Map<String,Integer> keywords = new HashMap<String,Integer>() {{
        put("someone", QuestionParser.SOMEONE);
        put("fred", QuestionParser.FRED);
        put("henry", QuestionParser.HENRY);
    }};
}

question
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 1746");}
    :   expr+ EOF
    ;

expr
    :   ID SOMEONE
    |   ID FRED
    |   ID HENRY
    ;

ID  : [a-zA-Z0-9_.]+ ;

BACKTICK_ID : '`' ID '`'
        { String textb = getText();
          String texta = textb.substring(1, textb.length() - 1);
          System.out.println("text before=" + textb + ", text after="+ texta);
          if ( keywords.containsKey(texta)) {
              setType(keywords.get(texta)); // reset token type
              setText(texta); // remove backticks
          }
        }
    ;

WS : [ \r\n\t] -> skip ;
```

Execution :

```
$ grun Question question -tokens -diagnostics t.text 
text before=`someone`, text after=someone
text before=`fred`, text after=fred
text before=`henry`, text after=henry
[@0,0:2='one',<ID>,1:0]
[@1,4:12='someone',<4>,1:4]
[@2,14:16='two',<ID>,2:0]
[@3,18:23='fred',<5>,2:4]
[@4,25:28='tree',<ID>,3:0]
[@5,30:36='henry',<6>,3:5]
[@6,38:37='<EOF>',<EOF>,4:0]
Question last update 1746
$ cat Question.tokens 
ID=1
BACKTICK_ID=2
WS=3
SOMEONE=4
FRED=5
HENRY=6
```

As you can see, there are no more errors because the `expr` rule is happy with well identified tokens. Even if there are no

```
SOMEONE : 'someone' ;
FRED    : 'fred' ;
HENRY   : 'henry' ;
```

only `ID` and `BACKTICK_ID`, the `types` have been defined behind the scene by the `tokens` statement :

```
    public static final int
        ID=1, BACKTICK_ID=2, WS=3, SOMEONE=4, FRED=5, HENRY=6;
```

I'm afraid that if you want a free list of names, it's not possible because the parser works with `types`, not the name of lexer rules :

```
    public static class ExprContext extends ParserRuleContext {
        public TerminalNode ID() { return getToken(QuestionParser.ID, 0); }
        public TerminalNode SOMEONE() { return getToken(QuestionParser.SOMEONE, 0); }
        public TerminalNode FRED() { return getToken(QuestionParser.FRED, 0); }
        public TerminalNode HENRY() { return getToken(QuestionParser.HENRY, 0); }
...
public final ExprContext expr() throws RecognitionException {
    try { ...
        setState(17);
        case 1:
            enterOuterAlt(_localctx, 1);
            {
            setState(11);
            match(ID);
            setState(12);
            match(SOMEONE);
            }
            break;
```

In

```
match(SOMEONE);
```

`SOMEONE` is a constant representing the number 4.

If you don't have a list of known names, `emit` will not solve your problem because it creates a Token whose most important field is `_type` :

```
public Token emit() {
    Token t = _factory.create(_tokenFactorySourcePair, _type, _text, _channel, _tokenStartCharIndex, getCharIndex()-1,
                              _tokenStartLine, _tokenStartCharPositionInLine);
    emit(t);
    return t;
}
```